# Google PageSpeed Insights - need to fix

Tags: jquery, html, css, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

My website seems to have a very slow load speed on mobile phones, I have tried to use the google PageSpeed insights and try and rectify the issue

I cannot seem to understand what exactly i need to change using the screenshot

Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: You seem to have either two different versions of jQuery loading, or full and minified copies of the same version. Is that intentional? Are all of these scripts needed for initial display of your site, or can some be loaded at the *end* of the `body` (or with `async` enabled)?

Comment: Did you click the text [Remove render-block JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS)? It links to a page that explains it all. You can also click the text [Optimize CSS Deliver](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) and learn how to fix those issues also. For the JS you'll likely have to minify and move the JS from the head to the footer of your page (or lazy load it). For the CSS you'll likely have to minify it also. There's a chance that concatenation would be an option for both your JS and CSS.

Comment: Yes I have - however, I have placed the jquery files at the bottom and still no difference

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down and deal with it in two parts, the JS and the CSS.

### JavaScript

Starting off with the JavaScript, the web page needs to wait until it has finished downloading and parsing the JS file before it can start rendering the page. If you mark the JS tag as "async" like the example below, you let the browser know that it doesnt need to block until the JS is fully downloaded. Instead it will start to render the page immedidately.

```
<script src="demo_async.js" async></script>
```

Checkout [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) for more information.

### CSS

The [Google Developers site](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/PrioritizeCriticalCss) gives a great insight as to why your CSS is blocking the render of the page. Because there is some CSS that is required to paint and render the first viewport's worth of layout. This CSS is known as the critical CSS. Try to rather prioritize Critical CSS parses the CSS and replaces it with inlined CSS that contains only the rules used on the page. This avoids any blocking CSS requests needed for the initial render. I recommend having a look at the [Filament Group website](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/performance-rwd.html) for more information.